# Authorization with Node JS application

Tags: node.js, angular, authorization

I have an Angular 2 app with node js as back end. I am wondering, how to authenticate user when I for example want to restrict access. Now, I am using bearer token and keeping users' sessions in dictionary [token] => user object. I am not sure if this is a good solution because if someone will steal token, then could use particular users' account.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can set expiration duration for your JWT tokens.
Avoid updating credentials(email,password etc) only on the basis of Token.
 [More](https://auth0.com/forum/t/stealing-jwt-from-authenticated-user/352/2)